# How to modify vectorDrawable in Android

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I have a vectorDrawable like this:

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="1668dp"
    android:height="1160dp"
    android:viewportWidth="1668.0"
    android:viewportHeight="1160.0">

    <path
        android:pathData="M586,394.3 L291.8,394.3 277.7,497.1 270.7,508.3 270.7,650.5 277.7,664.6 293.2,765.9 581.8,765.9"
        android:strokeLineCap="butt"
        android:strokeColor="#000000"
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:strokeWidth="5"
        android:strokeLineJoin="miter"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"/>

    <path
        android:pathData="M581.6,394.3C581.6,394.3 539.4,473.1 539.4,505.5 539.4,537.9 539.4,611.1 539.4,651.9 539.4,692.7 581.6,765.9 581.6,765.9"
        android:strokeLineCap="butt"
        android:strokeColor="#000000"
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:strokeWidth="2"
        android:strokeLineJoin="miter"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"/>
</vector>
```

Is there a tool that allow to me to modify the vector using a IDE or something similar ? (Drag & drop ecc)

Comment: convert back to SVG then use any SVG editor then reimport drawable

Comment: How i can convert back ?

Comment: Learn how SVG looks like ... create two paths in svg copy `android:pathData` to proper svg path's attribute [(AFAIK it is `d`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)

Comment: Try using vector asset studio : https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html

Comment: I'd like to modify too